# The host HOST does not support SSL connections

Tags: mysql, asp.net, server, web-config

I am getting this server error when publishing my site to our host.

[image]

I cannot replicate this error with any of our other sites on this hosting service. I have also tried using the SslMode="none" within the connectionstrings of the webconfig file, but that also crashes as the webconfig xml does not recognize the SslMode field.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and for me worked when I added `SslMode=none` into my connection string, see how I did =>

```
"ConnectionString": "Server=domain;Database=xxx;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;UseAffectedRows=False;AllowUserVariables=True;SslMode=none;"
```